# Retornar el valor del subscribe por fuera de este y usar async/await

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, mapbox

Estoy tratando de que al enviar una información de un componente A(Padre) un componente B(Nieto), el que lo recibe, pueda primero ejecutar el proceso de este, y luego el código que viene debajo de este. Ya que me está dando problema de hacer un proceso cuando retorna un valor desde la función desde el servicio.

**Angular v10**

**rxjs v6.5**

#### services

```
private send_data = new Subject<any>();

sendDataToMap(dataToMap: []) {
    this.send_data.next(dataToMap);
  }

  reciveDataToMap(): Observable<any>{
    return this.send_data.asObservable();
  }

getDataToRenderOnMap(dataToMap){

    dataToMap.forEach((data) => {

      this.routesList.push(data?.mbl_vessels?.path);

      const currentPos: number[] = Object.values(data?.mbl_vessels?.currentPosition);
      this.pointsToFit.push(currentPos);

      const marker: IMarker = {
        transportType: data?.quote?.transportationMode,
        currentPosition: currentPos
      }

      this.markersToRender.push(marker);

    });

    return {
      routesList: this.routesList,
      pointsToFit: this.pointsToFit,
      markersToRender: this.markersToRender
    }

  }
```

#### component A - send data

```
this.elementsToMap = elementsReq.data.filter(item => item.hasOwnProperty('mbl_vessels'));
this.miniMapService.sendDataToMap(this.elementsToMap);
```

#### component B - received data

```
ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.loadMap(MapStyles.COLOR_STYLE);
    this.loadMapControls();

    this.prepareDataToMap();

    //La idea es ejecutar esto, solo cuando termine el proceso de la data


    this.setLineStyle(LinePathColor.TO_COLOR, geoData);
    this.setCustomMarkers();
    this.setMarkerForBounding(shipmentsDataPosition);

    this.cdref.detectChanges();
  }

prepareDataToMap(){
    this.miniMapService.reciveDataToMap().subscribe((data) => {
      this.dataToMap = data;
      this.dataReturned = this.miniMapService.getDataToRenderOnMap(this.dataToMap);
    });
  }

setLineStyle(colorPath: string, route?) {

    this.mapa.on('load', () => {
      this.mapa.addSource('route', {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': {
          'type': 'Feature',
          'properties': {},
          'geometry': {
            'type': 'LineString',
            'coordinates': route
          }
        }
      });

      this.mapa.addLayer({
        'id': 'route',
        'type': 'line',
        'source': 'route',
        'layout': {
          'line-join': 'round',
          'line-cap': 'round'
        },
        'paint': {
          'line-color': colorPath,
          'line-width': 2,
          "line-dasharray": [0.2, 2]
        }
      });
    });

  }
```

Con relación a la función que esta abajo que dibuja una ruta, solo lo hace si la `data` se la paso estática, pero, si uso un ciclo sea `forEach` o `map`, simplemente no funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Se puede convertir el observable en una promesa usando `lastValueFrom` y usar `await` para que el código se vuelva secuencial:

```
async prepareDataToMap(){
        const data = await lastValueFrom(this.miniMapService.reciveDataToMap())
        this.dataToMap = data;
        this.dataReturned = this.miniMapService.getDataToRenderOnMap(this.dataToMap);
      }
```

Luego en el `ngAfterViewInit` se usa `await` para esperar que la función termine:

```
async ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.loadMap(MapStyles.COLOR_STYLE);
    this.loadMapControls();

    await this.prepareDataToMap();
    // resto del código
```

Comment: Voy a probar, pero una pregunta extra, de esta forma no es de rxjs 7 u 8 en adelante?

Comment: Sí, rxjs v7. Si fuera en versiones anteriores se puede reemplazar por `const data = await this.miniMapService.reciveDataToMap().toPromise()`

Comment: Déjame pruebo ese último porque tengo versión 6.5 creo en el proyecto, y casi no se cambia nada porque es viejo este.

Comment: Amigo, no me funciona, y tampoco me lanza ningún error, de hecho, ni siquiera me ejecuta las funciones debajo del `await`

Comment: Puede ser porque se bloquea el `ngAfterViewInit` el cual es una función del ciclo de vida de Angular. Prueba extrayendo todo el código  a una función aparte. Quedando algo así `ngAfterViewInit() { this.codigoDeInicio() }`

Comment: Ya mismo pruebo, dame un momento

Comment: No funciona tampoco, lo hice a como entendí de esta forma, [nueva prueba](https://imgur.com/7TnNn8i)

Comment: No, mueve todo lo que está en `ngAfterViewInit` a la función nueva.

Comment: No funciona tampoco amigo, que podría ser?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140784/discussion-between-lobos-and-pedro-miguel-pimienta-morales).